# React.js code is not running after installing it using nodejs through npm installer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, package.json

I was trying to learn react, so I have this sample code of my first react app, and I am trying to get it work but after running npm install followed by npm start I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\reactapp>npm start

> reactapp@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\reactapp
> webpack-dev-server --hot

The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI
-> When using npm: npm i -D webpack-cli
-> When using yarn: yarn add -D webpack-cli
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\reactapp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:60:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-07T07_08_01_594Z-debug.log
```

Don't know how to solve this issue.
Here is my log file.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~prestart: reactapp@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: reactapp@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\reactapp\node_modules\.bin;G:\Software files\Python\Scripts\;G:\Software files\Python\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;G:\Software files\Brackets Editor\command;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Ak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\Ak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;G:\Software files\Java\bin;C:\Users\Ak\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;G:\Software files\NMDVPN\bin;C:\Users\Ak\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\reactapp
10 silly lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack-dev-server --hot' ]
11 silly lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle reactapp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid reactapp@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\reactapp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning ReactJs with AK",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "npm",
    "learn",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "AK",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack": "^4.33.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.0"
  }
}
```

I have installed the react using Nodejs through npm installer.

Comment: It says it right there
> The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
> Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI

so `npm install webpack-cli`

Comment: Thanks for concern. I have installed the webpack command line interface. But the problem is still there, nothing has changed either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 3 lines of the error message advise what to do.

You need to install webpack-cli in order to run the webpack-dev-server. If you run the command it's giving you, you'll install webpack-cli as a devDependency and it'll all run.

If you're going to be using webpack a lot going forward it may be worth installing it globally, rather than needing to add it each time.

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI
-> When using npm: npm i -D webpack-cli
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me how to do that ?
React commands are not known to me afterall.

Comment: It's not a react command but should just be a case of installing the webpack-cli. If you run npm i -D webpack-cli it will be installed as a devDependency to the project, or you can run npm i -g webpack-cli and it'll be installed globally.

Try doing that and then rerun your app. If you're still getting an error post the error log and I'll have a look

Comment: I installed it globally, though it gave me a warning like:

npm WARN webpack-cli@3.3.3 requires a peer of webpack@4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ webpack-cli@3.3.3

At the end while running the code, still the same issue occurred.